# Netsuite - Schedule a report by script

Tags: report, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have requirement to create csv file from a reports and save this file in the file cabinet folder by Suite Script. Is it possible to do so. can reports be exported into csv file by script.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to do it:

var csvFile=file.create({
name:'test.csv',
contents:'xxxx',
folder:folderId,
fileType:'CSV'
});

csvFile.save();

Comment: Yes this will create csv file, but can we use this to create csv file for reports.